# How can I draw a 3D bone graphically

Tags: opengl, draw

I am working on 3D vertex skinning.  Everything is working fine.  I am now stuck on how to best represent my bones graphically.  I recognize that I can draw the bones as simple lines from one joint to the next.

However, I strongly want to draw something similar to that of blenders graphical representation of blender bones ( with heads and tails).

I sample code I have( below ) works however only for joints that are facing in the direction (0,1,0).  If I have a bone facing (1,0,0), then it does not accurately represent that bone.

So ultimately, my question is: is there a math equation to use to orientate these vertices from (0,1,0) to some arbitrary vector direction based on how my bone joints are facing.

```
glm::vec3 vert[14];
vert[ 0] = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vert[ 1] = glm::vec3(-0.2f, 0.2f,-0.2f);
vert[ 2] = glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f,-0.2f);
vert[ 3] = glm::vec3( 0.0f, getLength(), 0.0f);
vert[ 4] = glm::vec3(-0.2f, 0.2f,-0.2f);
vert[ 5] = glm::vec3(-0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
vert[ 6] = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vert[ 7] = glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f,-0.2f);
vert[ 8] = glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
vert[ 9] = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vert[10] = glm::vec3(-0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
vert[11] = glm::vec3( 0.0f, getLength(), 0.0f);
vert[12] = glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
vert[13] = glm::vec3(-0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
```

Comment: if you have the bone direction & orientation, you can construct a polyhedra around it with simple vector algebra. You could also build a "stock" model (on a primary axis), and then rotate & scale it to match the bone you wish to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a more general recipe, but may work for your problem.

You basically need a model lined up against an arbitrary direction, usually the vertical axis is used, but any would do. Then you may use the difference of the bone application points as a the destination vector, and the model axis as the origin vector. From then,:

- you compute the rotation quaternion between these vectors, as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another),
- and the scale factor by dividing the destination vector length by the origin vector length.
- You may repeat the first operation with the model facing vector, if the rendered one needs to be facing a specific direction.

You now have rotation and scale parameters to transform your model to the desired fit. Just turn these into a matrix, and apply it in your vertex transform stage.

[This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256133/opengl-managing-and-editing-large-amounts-of-line-strips) deals with rendering many instances of the same mesh, it might be helpful in getting an idea of how you may proceed once you have all the data ready.